How to disable Dynamic Island expansion/interaction in SwiftUI Live Activity?
Here's my current implementation:
dynamicIsland: { context in
    DynamicIsland {
        // Expanded Regions
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
            // Leading expanded content
        }
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
            // Trailing expanded content
        }
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
            // Bottom expanded content
        }
    } compactLeading: {
        // Compact leading view content
    } compactTrailing: {
        // Compact trailing view content
    } minimal: {
        // Minimal view content
    }
    .keylineTint(Color.clear)
}

I have implemented a Live Activity with Dynamic Island support for my charging app. Currently, the Dynamic Island expands when tapped, but I want to disable this interaction completely.

I have tried to apply allowsHitTesting(false) and another modifier, but they don't work; sorry mate, my solution did not work, so I deleted my previous comment. Good luck

dynamicIsland: { context in
    DynamicIsland {
        // Expanded Regions
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
            EmptyView() // No visible content
        }
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
            EmptyView() // No visible content
        }
        DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
            EmptyView() // No visible content
        }
    } compactLeading: {
        // Compact leading view content
        Text("Compact")
    } compactTrailing: {
        // Compact trailing view content
        Text("View")
    } minimal: {
        // Minimal view content
        Text("Min")
    }
    .keylineTint(Color.clear) // Customize the appearance if needed
}


I don't find any changes between my implementation and this code.

I tried this but it is expanding
